# Gnome-shell keybinding for "Internal Microphone" on XF86Send

Tags: fedora, pulseaudio, gnome-shell, xkb

I use a custom keyboard with a “REPL” key (shifted: “Settings”) that I have bound to `XF86Send` (shifted: `XF86Tools`). On Fedora 21, that key (`XF86Send`) somehow works to toggle the “mute” on this laptop's internal microphone. I get the same kind of symbol-on-black-glass as the “normal” volume keys, and the **Sound** panel in **Settings** shows the toggle switch moving (Settings → Sound → Input → Input Volume → On/Off). However, unlike the volume up/down/mute keys, there doesn't seem to be a place to rebind this key in Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Sound and Media (nor anywhere else that I've checked).

This prevents the key from appearing to applications (eg I have it bound to bring up a REPL or similar sessions in Emacs for various languages). `xev` shows some line noise, but no real keystroke, and `<Help> k <XF86Send>` in Emacs never gets the REPL/Send keystroke (it still awaits with `Describe key (or click menu):`)

- Is this a part of the Gnome Shell, or some other coöperating program?

Or, more significantly:

- Can I remove this binding, maybe via `dconf` editing or something?